# How to implement drop shape which contain text inside it in react native as shown in below image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I wnat to implement drop shape which contain text inside it in react native as shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Tim said you can use an SVG to achieve this. However, your shape is also drawable by taking advantage of rotations and the border-radius property.

I've made a really basic snack on expo.io that should get you started.

[Basic droplet](https://snack.expo.io/@ajthyng/jealous-raisins)

[image]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1
      }}>
        <View style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
          borderTopRightRadius: 20,
          borderBottomLeftRadius: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'tomato',
          transform: [{ rotateZ: '45deg' }]
        }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', transform: [{ rotateZ: '-45deg' }], fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 14 }}>
            12.4
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really like your solution! +1 but it would be better to include your code here as well

Comment: Good idea Tim, I added the code directly to the answer.

Comment: Such a clever, elegant and perfect solution. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a svg with a drop shape as background.

As example you can use the following svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 18 22" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/"><path d="M9.005,20.319l-5.66,-5.66c-1.501,-1.5 -2.345,-3.537 -2.345,-5.659c0,-4.389 3.611,-8 8,-8c4.389,0 8,3.611 8,8c0,2.122 -0.844,4.159 -2.345,5.659l-5.65,5.66Z" style="fill:#f00;fill-rule:nonzero;"/></svg>
```

Just save it as file. I saved it as droplet.svg.

Then you can use `react-native-svg-uri` to display the svg file:

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
import droplet from './droplet.svg';
```

inside your render function:

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
<SvgUri source={droplet} width="50" height="50" fill="blue" fillAll/>
<Text style={{position: 'absolute', color: 'white' }}> 23 </Text>
</View>
```

Output:

[image: output]